# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException no event down from INITIALIZED

Tags: android, android-activity

Not sure what I changed in the application but I'm getting this untraceable stack trace all of a sudden after a release (I updated a few dependencies but not sure which is causing it cause I cannot replicate.

```
atal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event down from INITIALIZED
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:281)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:302)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:62)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3130)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:706)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1407)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1477)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1555)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1608)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3046)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroyView(FragmentManager.java:3018)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:3128)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroyFragmentView(FragmentStateManager.java:706)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1407)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1477)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1555)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2150)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2061)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1957)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3056)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2983)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2923)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:562)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1324)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2392)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2137)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2061)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1957)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3056)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2990)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:458)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7338)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:186)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:171)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:148)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:76)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1988)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7240)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:883)
```

Comment: Hey, Man did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the answer you have to go back to alpha06 if you're after that release.

Comment: Didn’t solve for me, I am calling activity.recreate() method and got that error.

Comment: Are you using any dependency that also has that version? My problem was that am using a library (Which we maintain) that had that version and that overwritten the version we had in our current project's build.gradle, there  shouldn't by any of that version in any library used.

Comment: Yes I am using ktx.fragment and ktx.activity dependencies

Answer (score 27):

The [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138645)'s fix is now stable in `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0`.

Comment: alpha06 seems to have the same issue for me

Comment: Make sure that if you're using an android module or library that it also uses alpha06 or below.

Comment: Do you know if this problem was reported ?

Comment: You mean.. to Google? @extmkv .. Even if it is, this is the current workaround

Comment: Note: still broken on alpha08

Comment: Since October 1 is available 1.3.0-beta01 version. Can someone confirm that the bug is present on this version?

Comment: I'm using 1.3.0-beta1 and can confirm that the issue is still there.

Comment: @AhmedI.Khalil please share a reproducible sample

Comment: Still broken, I get this error when I toggle device from light mode to dark or from dark mode to light when app is running

Comment: reverting to 1.3.0-alpha06 helped !! 1.3.0-beta01 doesn't solved

Comment: Issue is still present on 1.3.0-beta02 as well.

Comment: I just installed rc1 - that seems to bring back the issue..

Comment: rc1 still has the issue

Comment: I've created an report, please take a look and feel free to star.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176758182

Comment: That issue was a duplicate. Star this one instead: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138645

Comment: Similar? alpha06 ok, rc02 > 
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event up from DESTROYED
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:263)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:121)

Comment: 1.3.0-rc2 fixed it again

Comment: wow, androidx.appcompat 1.3.0-beta01 seems to introduce the same issue. Going back to 1.3.0-alpha02 fixes it

(for me in conjunction with androidx.fragment 1.2.5)

Comment: I just got this crash on fragment 1.4.0-rc01

Answer (score 6):

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138645) has been fixed and is now [stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0).

Usage: `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0`

Answer (score 3):

Had this error when `navController.navigate` inside `onCreate` so i moved the code that checks the intent to `onResume` - problem solved

Answer (score 2):

This crash is happening because the ids between the navigation and the start destination are the same. Your navigation and destinations should have unique ids.

For example:

This is crash:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@id/main">
```

This is correct:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        app:startDestination="@id/main_fragment">
```

Comment: Mine are different, still happened with that version.

Comment: Is it 1.3.0-beta01?

Answer (score 2):

If this is happening in compose tests you need to call `navHostController.navigate(...)`
from inside a Composable, i.e. inside

```
composeRule.setContent { 
     navHostController.navigate(...) 
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work , thats my exact use case

Comment: Did you put the navigate() call in the right place, did you create a question I could look at?

Comment: yes you were right I put the navigate called inside the "@"Before , now that i Moved it into my "@"Test and abstract the navHostController to a variable member, it works fine. Thanks

Comment: This works because composition happens on the main thread. However, there is no guarantee that that will always be the case.
`setContent`'s lambda is composable, so the usual rules for side effects in composition apply here (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). Please make sure you navigate in an effect, just like you would in production code.

Alternatively, ensure you are on the main thread using `composeTestRule.runOnUiThread { /* navigate here */ }`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this while writing a test involving navigation-compose. Make sure that you are calling `navigate` on the main thread, for example by using [`ComposeTestRule#runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/ComposeTestRule#runOnUiThread(kotlin.Function0)).

```kotlin
@Test
fun testNavControllerNavigates() {
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    rule.setContent {
        navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController, ...) { ... }
    }

    rule.runOnUiThread { navController.navigate(...) }
    // runOnIdle works too :)
}
```

Alternatively, you could call it from an effect defined in your composable.

```kotlin
@Test
fun testNavControllerNavigates() {
    var destination by mutableStateOf("A")
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    rule.setContent {
        LaunchedEffect(destination) {
            navController.navigate(destination)
        }
        navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController, ...) { ... }
    }

    destination = "B"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me after updating below version of fragment dependency. it wokking

```
androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start Activity in Fragment, change:

```
val intent = Intent(**requireContext()**, HomeActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
startActivity(intent)
```

to

```
val intent = Intent(**requireActivity()**, HomeActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
startActivity(intent)
```